# Invalid regular expression flags in A:\Github\genshin-project\views\admin\admin-incl\topnav.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: ejs

So I have this code:

```
<!-- including top navbar -->
<%- include('admin-incl/topnav'); %>

<!-- including side navbar -->
<%- include('admin-incl/sidenav'); %>
```

an I have those files in those directories, but it shows me this error:
`Invalid regular expression flags in A:\Github\genshin-project\views\admin\admin-incl\topnav.ejs while compiling ejs`

I tried changing directories, and when I have those files in my `viewes/includes` it works